# Scala compile server error when using nailgun

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, nailgun

I am currently using IntelliJ Idea 13.0 Build 132.197, and I frequently run into this problem when building any Scala projects

```
6:08:42 PM Scala compile server: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGServer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

This error happens when I have only 1 project open, and without using nailgun in any other processes. Closing and re-opening the project does not work. I still get the same error after Exiting from IntelliJ and re-starting it.

In Windows Task Manager, I see a `java.exe` process with the following details:

```
E:\Dev\Java\bin\java -cp "E:/Dev/Java/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 132.197/lib/jps-server.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 132.197/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 132.197/lib/util.jar;C:/Users/hanxue/.IntelliJIdea13/config/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-library.jar;C:/Users/hanxue/.IntelliJIdea13/config/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-plugin-runners.jar;C:/Users/hanxue/.IntelliJIdea13/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/nailgun.jar;C:/Users/hanxue/.IntelliJIdea13/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/sbt-interface.jar;C:/Users/hanxue/.IntelliJIdea13/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/incremental-compiler.jar;C:/Users/hanxue/.IntelliJIdea13/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/jline.jar;C:/Users/hanxue/.IntelliJIdea13/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/scala-jps-plugin.jar" -Xmx1024m -server -Xss1m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.nailgun.NailgunRunner 3200
```

Is this because of an issue with Nailgun settings?

Answer (score 48):

Here is a manual solution of a such situation:

- find the process (PID) listening on port 3200 (check it in settings>scala>tcp port)

  - on Mac(Linux): `lsof -i :3200`
- check that process

  - on Mac(Linux): `ps axu |grep <PID>`
  - in my case it ended with `org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.nailgun.NailgunRunner 3200`
- kill the process, it is some old one and IDEA will start the new one

  - on Mac(Linux): `kill -9 <PID>`